# How to get rid of from browser demanding server credentials every time?

Tags: asp.net, deployment

My browser always demands server credentials where i have deployed my application, i am not getting it, so do i need to make some setting in My web config file?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your app is configured to use integrated windows authentication and you are using a different browser than IE.

If you go to control panel-> administrative tools-> IIS Manager and browse to your app, you'll be able to adjust these settings from there.

Depending on the nature of the app and your requirements, you can enable anonymous acces to your app from IIS or, if that's not an option, simply configure your browser to save the credentials to access your website.

Comment: mine is forms authentication........i can not give client credentials...just i want to know is it more to do with C-panel or my application's web config.

Comment: I am not familiar with cpanel but post the relevant parts of your web.config

Comment: I did not so any changes to web config, it just absolutely default, web config for .net framework 4.0